# USB 3 female connector and signal assignment from TYPE-A to TYPE-C for connector reversibility

Tags: usb-host

I'm designing a USB HUB and I've a question regarding the upstream connector. From my understanding this should be a female type. Now the question is how match the USB-C signals on the two side of the connector.

Regarding this schematic:

[image: TYPE C signal disposition]

The question is if connecting together these signal pins is correct to achieve connector reversibility:

A2 (TX1+) with B2 (TX2+)

A3 (TX1-) with B3 (TX2-)

A11 (RX2+) with B11 (RX1+)

A10 (RX2-) with B10 (RX1-)

A6 (D+) with B6 (D+)

A7 (D-) with B7 (D-)

The GND pins will be connected together, as will the VBUS pins. For the other signals, I think that I can leave them open, because I only need to be compatible with the classic 9-pin USB 3 connector (like the WURTH 692122030100 model) but instead through the use of a TYPE-C style or it is mandatory to use a 9 pin USB 3 connector instead?

My HUB will be bus-powered so I've to connect in some special way also the CC1/CC2 signals? Into the HUB controller that I'm using (TUSB8020B) there is no note about these pins.

**WURTH 6921220300100**

[image]

**TYPE-C HRO connector (LCSC C165948)**

[image]

Comment: There are four GND and four VBUS pins, each set should all be connected together. To use Type C connectors you would need to implement the correct power switching using the CC pins, this chip doesn't support that as it's designed for USB 3 A and B connectors.

Comment: @Finbarr, on the "two GND and two VBUS" bit in the question, that's my fault where I edited it, not the OP's. Was supposed to the two ends of the cable rather than pins. Fixed now.

Comment: After some research the best solution (compliant with the standard) would be use a TYPE-B receptacle on the upstream port or a cable with TYPE-A male plug sodered at one end or directly use a TYPE-A male plug soldered on the PCB which basically is equivalent to a cable with length equal to 0.